# Installing Composer and Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have installed `composer` in windows platform. But when am trying to install the `composer.phar` through this command, 
`php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`

it's giving me this error-

> Warning: readfile(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open
>   stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected par ty did
>   not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond.   in Command line
>   code on line 1.

The internet configuration is OK. Please help. Am going through a hell of time...installing `Laravel` .

Comment: Problep still persist? You are doing it properly.

Comment: Composer is nothing but a script, you can download it manually (see the bottom of their [download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/)) and place it inside the folder where you would like to download Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Had also some problem with the installation.
At the end I used the installer:

https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

## Installing with installer

That line just pulls and outputs a file that contains a PHP script that will actually install Composer, thats why it is piped to PHP in the end of the line.

If `readfile` doesn't work, you can simply download the file with your browser by saving the file from https://getcomposer.org/installer then execute it from the folder where you downloaded:

```
cat ~/installer | php
```

Assuming that you downloaded it to your home `~` folder with the name `installer`.

## Manual installation

It also worth mentioning that this installer just makes a few checks after it copies the actual `composer.phar` file, that you can download by yourself from the bottom of the [download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/), with the link named: [Latest Snapshot](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar)

Thats all. By downloading that file you technically "installed" Composer. Just go to the folder where you downloaded it and you can start to use it:

```
php composer.phar
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But its not working. No matter which way i try, its giving this error back..                                                                                   
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed be
  cause the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
   host has failed to respond.

Comment: @JohnMuthoni But that means your Composer works fine, you just misconfigured something. Did you at least tried to search the exception or the error message? There are thousands of questions about that. Like [this](http://laravel.io/forum/01-27-2015-composerdownloadertransportexception-while-trying-to-install-laravel-42) and [this](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2724) and [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/composer-stopped-working-cant-figure-out).

Comment: @JohnMuthoni Also at least update your question with your current status, including the error message, the code you wrote and what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I the solution above didn't work for me. So I found another way for time being to make things moving. So, I used Larapack. I know that's like running away from problems but it worth it for now. As I move on, I will find a way round.
Thanks a lot guys for your help.